# Merge IQueryables of derived types

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have three types that derive from the same base class: BaseEvent.

I display all three types together in a datagrid in my frontend. Need to maintain each items knowledge of what type it is so that I can cast it to the appropriate type when handling it in the front end.
I had it working by converting each set to a list, but I'd like to return IQueryable instead so that it can be more efficiently filtered.

```
public override IQueryable<BaseEvent> GetAllItems()
{

    var freestyleEvents = _context.Set<Freestyle>()
                    .Include(ev => ev.Venue)
                    .Include(ev => ev.EventImage)
                    .Include(ev => ev.BookingOption)
                    .Include(ev => ev.Business)
                    .Include(ev => ev.Tickets!).ThenInclude(ticket => ticket.TicketOption);

    var workshopEvents = _context.Set<Workshop>()
                    .Include(ev => ev.Venue)
                    .Include(ev => ev.EventImage)
                    .Include(ev => ev.BookingOption)
                    .Include(ev => ev.Business)
                    .Include(ev => ev.Tickets!).ThenInclude(ticket => ticket.TicketOption);

    var classNightEvents = _context.Set<ClassNight>()
                    .Include(ev => ev.Venue)
                    .Include(ev => ev.EventImage)
                    .Include(ev => ev.BookingOption)
                    .Include(ev => ev.Business)
                    .Include(ev => ev.Tickets!).ThenInclude(ticket => ticket.TicketOption);


    return freestyleEvents.OfType<BaseEvent>().Concat(workshopEvents.OfType<BaseEvent>()).Concat(classNightEvents.OfType<BaseEvent>());


}
```

This returns a runtime error

> Expression of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[BaseEvent.Model.Freestyle]' cannot be used for parameter of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[BaseEvent.Model.Workshop]' of method 'System.Linq.IQueryable`1[BaseEvent.Model.Workshop] Concat[Workshop](System.Linq.IQueryable`1[BaseEvent.Model.Workshop], System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[BaseEvent.Model.Workshop])'

How can I write this so it works?

Comment: add  ` .Cast<BaseEvent>().ToList(); ` as the last line of each var.  then your result would be `var allEvents = freestyleEvents.Concat(workshopEvents).Concat(classNightEvents).AsQueryable();` this however will materialize your data so you will lose the benefits of deferred execution

Comment: You don't need to query the derived entities separately and can simply query the (possibly) abstract base entity.

Comment: If I query the abstract base entity then I will have a collection of BaseEvents without the extended properties contained in the derived types.
NB I'm using TPT in EF - the BaseEvent table only contains the common properties.

Comment: @BryanDellinger I'd like to maintain the benefits of deferred execution if possible.

Comment: @tonydev314 If you are using TPT or TPH/TPC, i.e. any EF Core inheritance strategy, which means `BaseEvent` is not just a base *class*, but base *entity*, then `_context.Set<BaseEvent>().Include(...)` will return all you are asking for without a need of manual `Concat`s. Polymorphic queries against base entity set and materializing the results with the correct derived class instances is one of the main benefits of using EF Core inheritance.

Comment: @IvanStoev Wow - I didn't expect that! Thank you.